# MultiAutoCompleteTextView and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, multiautocompletetextview

I have a list of Tags stored in Firebase. In one of my Fragments, a **MultiAutoCompleteTextView** (MACTV) lets the User, to select the relevant Tags.

The objective,

- Is to populate the Array (used in ArrayAdapter for MACTV) using the
  Tags from Firebase.
- Once the user selects the relevant Tags from    MACTV using
  OnItemClickListener, the selected Tags needs to be saved    to
  Firebase.

Here's how I tried implementing.

*Defining the ArrayAdapter for MACTV*:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterMultiAutoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

*Using the AddValueEventListener to populate the ArrayAdapter*

```
if (fbUser != null) {
  dbTags.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      //Basically, this says "For each DataSnapshot *Data* in dataSnapshot, do what's inside the method.
          for (DataSnapshot tagNameSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          //Get the suggestion by childing the key of the string you want to get.
              String ValueTagName = tagNameSnapshot.child("tagName")).getValue(String.class);
          //Add ValueTagName to ArrayAdapter
              adapterMultiAutoComplete.add(ValueTagName);
          }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {/*Do Nothing*/}
   });
}
```

*Code for MACTV*

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView articleTags = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mactv_tags);
articleTags.requestFocus();
articleTags.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
articleTags.setAdapter(adapterMultiAutoComplete);
```

*Saving the selected tags to Firebase*

```
List<String> ArticleTags = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(articleTags.getText().toString().split(", ")));
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tags").setValue(ArticleTags);
```

The Threshold value is defined as 2. Unfortunately, no relevant tags appear as pop-up when I start typing in MACTV.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Just add this line inside onDataChange() method after adding item to adapter. adapterMultiAutoComplete.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Related (not duplicate) question with answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39715702/5593959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, great question! The most interesting I've seen this month.

First of all, with this code you loading whole `tags` node to device. Imagine, you have 2M of tags (does SO has?), will this code still work? ;)

The second thing, code inside `onDataChange` (as well as code in all firebase callbacks) is called on worker thread, but adapter methods should be called in UI thread.

And the last, here is how I see the solution:

1. You need to use Queries (you can read more in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data))
2. First of all, we need to sort tags by name. So this is base query:

   ```
   DatabaseReference baseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tags").orderByChild("tagName");
   ```
3. Next - you must attach `TextWatcher` to your `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` with following code

   ```
   articleTags.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

           if (charSequence.length <3) return;

           String searchTarget = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
           //Here magic happens)
           baseRef.startAt(searchTarget).endAt(searchTarget + "\uf8ff").limitToFirst(20).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   //Handle executing this code in main thread yourself, answer will be too long with it
                   adapterMultiAutoComplete.removeAll();
                   for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        adapterMultiAutoComplete.add(data.getValue(String.class))
                   }
                   adapterMultiAutoComplete.notifyDatasetChanged();
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                  Log.wtf("What a terrible failure!", databaseError.toException());
               }
           });

       }

       @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}

   });
   ```

P.S.: Code never tested and probably not working. But you got the idea ;)

Comment: Thanks for introducing the alternate perspective towards the solution. I didn't think of using Queries earlier. But which is the better way? _Case 01:_ Using For loop to fetch all the available tagNames. In this case, upside being faster searches, but doesn't make sense when involving too many tags. In _Case 02:_ (using queries), too much search time involved (say when I wish to search and add ten tags)

Comment: @user3314337 set limit to 100, for example. If you got less than 100 values, save them in adapter and don't make more queries =)